# Create a hierarchy data structure from list of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

I want to write a python script to convert my list of data into hierarchy data structure. So to explain more, the first data will always be the root node,and each data has its own id, and `user_id` is the id of the ancestor. So if the data's `user_id` is others `id` then the data should be the children node of the others node

This is my original data

```
[
    {
        "user_id": 1164146,
        "id": 1158720,
        "ancestors": ",8,77169,1164146,",
        <OTHER DATA>
    },
    {
        "user_id": 1158720,
        "id": 1259377,
        "ancestors": ",8,77169,1164146,1158720,",
        <OTHER DATA>
    },
    {
        "user_id": 1259377,
        "id": 1259378,
        "ancestors": ",8,77169,1164146,1158720,1259377,",
        <OTHER DATA>
    },
    {
        "user_id": 1158720,
        "id": 1259379,
        "ancestors": ",8,77169,1164146,1158720,",
        <OTHER DATA>
    }
]
```

And my result data is

```
[
    {
        "user_id": 1164146,
        "id": 1158720,
        "ancestors": ",8,77169,1164146,",
        <OTHER DATA>
        "children": [
            {
                "user_id": 1158720,
                "id": 1259377,
                "ancestors": ",8,77169,1164146,1158720,",
                <OTHER DATA>
                "children": [
                    {
                        "user_id": 1259377,
                        "id": 1259378,
                        "ancestors": ",8,77169,1164146,1158720,1259377,",
                        <OTHER DATA>
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "user_id": 1158720,
                "id": 1259379,
                "ancestors": ",8,77169,1164146,1158720,",
                <OTHER DATA>
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

From this example, the first data will be the root node, the second data (id:1259377) will be the child of first data (id:1158720) because the second node `user_id` is `1158720` which is the `id` of the first data. The actual data that I working on has more hierarchy level than this. Thank you for helping

I try to use ChatGPT to generate the code and it gave this code but the result isn't correct

```
def create_nested_structure(data):
    nested_data = []

    # The first data is the root node
    root = data[0]
    root["children"] = []

    for item in data[1:]:
        user_id = item["user_id"]

        # Find the parent node based on user_id
        parent = next((node for node in nested_data if node["user_id"] == user_id), None)

        if parent:
            if "children" not in parent:
                parent["children"] = []
            parent["children"].append(item)
        else:
            # If parent not found, add to the root node
            root["children"].append(item)

    nested_data.append(root)

    return nested_data
```

Comment: What is the relevance of `ancestors` here? It doesn't determine which is the ancestor in the hierarchy?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Actually the `ancestors` is the sequence of ancestor. So the last value of `ancestors` is the user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language model produced code that has a few mistakes:

- It never checks the "id" attribute, so it could never correctly identify a parent-child relationship. The comparison `node["user_id"] == user_id` should be `node["id"] == user_id`
- The iterator passed to `next()` iterates an empty collection `nested_data`, which of course makes no sense, as that means `parent` will always be assigned `None`. Only at the end of the function an item is appended to that `nested_data` collection. The iterator should iterate `data`, not `nested_data`.
- The `children` attribute is only added when there is at least one child, but your expected output also has that attribute in leaf-nodes.
- It assumes that the root node must be the first entry in the `data` input (to fair, you specified this). But we can imagine this is not necessarily so, and that there could even be more than one root (a *forest*).
- It looks for a matching parent by iterating the data -- for *each* node it visits -- which makes the algorithm inefficient for larger inputs. Instead of repeatedly calling `next`, we should use a dictionary for retrieving nodes by their id.

Here is how I would suggest doing it:

```
def create_nested_structure(data):
    # Define a "children" attribute for all nodes, and key them by id
    nodes = { obj["id"]: {**obj, "children": []} for obj in data }
    # Don't assume that the root is at index 0, nor that there is just one
    roots = []
    for obj in nodes.values():
        # If this node is a child...
        if obj["user_id"] in nodes:
            # ...then look up the parent in the dictionary, and connect them
            nodes[obj["user_id"]]["children"].append(obj)
        else:
            # ...otherwise it is a root
            roots.append(obj)
    return roots
```

As your input could define a hierarchy that has more than one root, the function returns a *list* of nodes, not a single node.

(and some day, a next language model will be fed with more data, including this, and not make that mistake again).